# Why don't I get the instance invite for personal story instances in a party?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am trying to play Guild Wars 2 with a guild mate and we're working through his personal story.

Many times this has worked seamlessly just by him trying to enter the personal story instance and me getting a pop up on my screen, with ten or so seconds to accept it. However, for the last few parts of his story I've not received an invite to the instance.

Is this due to certain parts of the story being solo only, or are we missing something more obvious than that?

Comment: Are you in the same map? You can't join story instances from separate maps (which is why it's harder to cross-realm Fractals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a party member initiates an instance, the game will ask each party member who is in the same zone if they would like to join in the instance.  Any party members outside the zone will be ignored.

This is further detailed on the 'join' box that pops up for party members;

[image]

As detailed on the above, there are three party members, but the join instance box only lists one (in addition to the person whose story it is) joining the instance.